# How to type a untyped package from NPM?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, typescript-typings

I'm learning typescript and I couldn't find the answer for this anywhere:

Suppose I have a module `./node_modules/do-something` that is written in plain JS:

```js
function doSometing(a = '', b = {}) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);

  return `${a}`;
}

module.exports = doSometing;
```

And I want to write type definitions for it. How should I go about doing?

I've tried:

```js
// do-someting/index.d.ts

declare module 'do-something' {
  export default interface doSometing {
    (a: string, b?: any): string
  }
}
```

But I always get `Cannot augment module 'do-something' because it resolves to a non-module entity`.

How should I go about typing it?

Answer (score 2):

You placing the extension in `node_modules/do-someting/index.d.ts`. Instead create a file `src/vendors.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'do-something' {
  export default interface doSometing {
    (a: string, b?: any): string
  }
}
```